# Custom post type archive page not showing content

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have registered a custom post type called `How to videos`.

```html
register_post_type(
  'How to videos',
  theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'how-to-videos', 'How to videos', 'How to videos',
    array(
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-video-alt3',
      'menu_position' => 20,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'public' => false,
      'supports' => array('title','thumbnail'),
    )
  )
);
```

The custom post type appears in the admin and I can successfully create posts.

I'm trying to create an `archive` template where I can display all of the posts in this post type (essentially create a level 1 page, there will be no level 2 pages).

To do this, I have created `archive-how-to-videos.php`, which looks like this:

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>
  this is a test
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As you can see, all I'm trying to do when accessing this `archive` at the moment is display dummy text. But, when accessing `/how-to-videos` it just shows the header and footer. When inspecting, the text "this is a test" is not on the page.

I have flushed permalinks via admin settings also. No avail.

I have other custom post types which are appearing as they should. Only difference between this post type and others is that, this one is the only one that has `'public' => false`.

Ideas on what's happening?

`theme_build_post_args`:

```html
class theme_PTTaxArgBuilder{

    /**
     * Options will be merged into these, as opposed to using
     * the standard WordPress defaults.
     * @var array
     */
    public $postDefaults = array(
        'public'                => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'                => array( 'slug' => '' ),
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail' ),
    );

    /**
     * Options will be merged into these, as opposed to using
     * the standard WordPress defaults.
     * @var array
     */
    public $taxonomyDefaults = array(
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => '' ),
    );

    /**
     * Build the post types labels based solely on the capitalised
     * singular and plural form.
     * @param string $singular Singular & capitalised form for the post type, eg 'Post'
     * @param string $plural   Plural & capitalised form for the post type, eg 'Posts'
     */
    public function buildPostLabels( $singular = 'Post', $plural = 'Posts' )
    {
        if($singular != 'Post' && $plural == 'Posts' ) {
            $plural = $singular . 's';
        }


        $labels = array(
            'name'               => _x($plural, 'post type general name', 'lightbox'),
            'singular_name'      => _x($singular, 'post type singular name', 'lightbox'),
            'menu_name'          => _x($plural, 'admin menu', 'lightbox'),
            'name_admin_bar'     => _x($singular, 'add new on admin bar', 'lightbox'),
            'add_new'            => _x('Add New', $singular, 'lightbox'),
            'add_new_item'       => __('Add New ' . $singular, 'lightbox'),
            'new_item'           => __('New ' . $singular, 'lightbox'),
            'edit_item'          => __('Edit ' . $singular, 'lightbox'),
            'view_item'          => __('View ' . $singular, 'lightbox'),
            'all_items'          => __('All ' . $plural, 'lightbox'),
            'search_items'       => __('Search ' . $plural, 'lightbox'),
            'parent_item_colon'  => __('Parent ' . $plural . ':', 'lightbox'),
            'not_found'          => __('No ' . strtolower($plural) . ' found.', 'lightbox'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No ' . strtolower($plural) . ' found in Trash.', 'lightbox'),
        );


        return $labels;
    }

    /**
     * Generate the complete arguments ready for post type creation,
     * including the URL slug and merging of new defaults above.
     * @param string $slug     The URL slug for the post type, eg 'posts'
     * @param string $singular Singular & capitalised form for the post type, eg 'Post'
     * @param string $plural   Plural & capitalised form for the post type, eg 'Posts'
     * @param array  $args     Additional arguments to override the defaults
     */
    public function buildPostArgs( $slug, $singular = 'Post', $plural = 'Posts', $args = array() )
    {
        $args = wp_parse_args($args, $this->postDefaults);

        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = $slug;

        $args['labels'] = $this->buildPostLabels($singular, $plural);

        return $args;
    }

    /**
     * Build the taxonomies labels based solely on the capitalised
     * singular and plural form.
     * @param string $singular Singular & capitalised form for the taxonomy, eg 'Category'
     * @param string $plural   Plural & capitalised form for the taxonomy, eg 'Categories'
     */
    public function buildTaxonomyLabels( $singular = 'Category', $plural = 'Categories' )
    {
        if($singular != 'Category' && $plural == 'Categories' ) {
            $plural = $singular . 's';
        }

        $labels = array(
            'name'                       => _x($plural, 'taxonomy general name'),
            'singular_name'              => _x($singular, 'taxonomy singular name'),
            'search_items'               => __('Search ' . $plural),
            'all_items'                  => __('All ' . $plural),
            'parent_item'                => __('Parent ' . $singular),
            'parent_item_colon'          => __('Parent ' . $singular . ':'),
            'edit_item'                  => __('Edit ' . $singular),
            'update_item'                => __('Update ' . $singular),
            'add_new_item'               => __('Add New ' . $singular),
            'new_item_name'              => __('New ' . $singular . ' Name'),
            'menu_name'                  => __($plural),
            // Tags
            'popular_items'              => __('Popular ' . $plural),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __('Separate ' . strtolower($plural) . ' with commas'),
            'add_or_remove_items'        => __('Add or remove ' . strtolower($plural)),
            'choose_from_most_used'      => __('Choose from the most used ' . strtolower($plural)),
            'not_found'                  => __('No ' . strtolower($plural) . ' found.'),
        );

        return $labels;
    }

    /**
     * Generate the complete arguments ready for taxonomy creation,
     * including the URL slug and merging of new defaults above.
     * @param string $slug     The URL slug for the taxonomy, eg 'category'
     * @param string $singular Singular & capitalised form for the taxonomy, eg 'Category'
     * @param string $plural   Plural & capitalised form for the taxonomy, eg 'Categories'
     * @param array  $args     Additional arguments to override the defaults
     */
    public function buildTaxonomyArgs( $slug, $singular = 'Category', $plural = 'Categories', $args = array() )
    {
        $args = wp_parse_args($args, $this->taxonomyDefaults);

        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = $slug;

        $args['labels'] = $this->buildTaxonomyLabels($singular, $plural);

        return $args;
    }
}

function theme_build_post_args( $slug, $singular = 'Post', $plural = 'Posts', $args = array() ){
    $builder = new theme_PTTaxArgBuilder;
    return $builder->buildPostArgs($slug, $singular, $plural, $args);
}
```

Comment: Do you have the [WP CLI ](https://wp-cli.org/) available? If you run `wp rewrite list` it will list out all the system rules, and I believe it is in order so the top-most wins. You are looking for the rule `faculty/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$` (where `faculty` is your CPT slug). If you don't see it, WP isn't aware of it. You can also pass `--match=faculty/` to filter that list to see what WP considers as valid options. Also, is it possible that `theme_build_post_args` does some unexpected things to the array that gets passed in, like change some assumed defaults?

Comment: Hi @ChrisHaas - I do not have the CLI available unfortunately. I have also updated my question to showcase the `theme_build_post_args` function

Comment: Thanks @Freddy, however it appears that `theme_build_post_args` is just a wrapper around `theme_PTTaxArgBuilder` so without that it doesn't help.

Comment: @ChrisHaas - You're right, I've updated the question with the full codebase related to `theme_build_post_args`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when accessing `/how-to-videos` it just shows the header and footer

I don't know why is that so, but `How to videos` is not a valid post type *key*.

More specifically, the first parameter for [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) is the post type key or slug, and **not** the post type label which is what you've actually used:

```php
register_post_type(
  'How to videos', // <- this should be how-to-videos
  theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'how-to-videos', 'How to videos', 'How to videos',
    ... your code.
  )
);
```

And because a post type key (should not exceed 20 characters and) may only contain lowercase alphanumeric characters, dashes, and underscores, then it means the above code would result in `howtovideos` being the post type key and not `how-to-videos`. (because the whitespaces are automatically *removed*)

Therefore, the archive template should have been named `archive-howtovideos.php` and *not* `archive-how-to-videos.php`.

Comment: Hi Sally, thanks again for solving another one of my issues! Can confirm changing to `archive-howtovideos.php` did the trick for me (: